# Shopify: How to collect statistics about listed applications I Shopify Store?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I would like to collect statistics about listed apps in Shopify Store, like number of listed apps, number of reviews for an app, installations, average rate, app category and so on without any private information about stores which have installed the application. I find several [blogs](https://blog.asoft.co/shopify-app-store-analysis-c8d9aab85ba7)  which managed to collect such info but unfortunately they are without open code. Is there any way to reach such info through API or something?

**UPD**

I have found ready-made solution on github https://github.com/usernam3/shopify-app-store-scraper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any open source web scraper to deal with that. Simply scrape the Shopify App store, and build your stats.

You need no API. Just scripting of your own device. Pretty basic stuff.